# Viewing 3D layers in a 2D density plot

Tags: r, 3d

Is there a way to plot [this dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zcTxkstAJ4qTNPa2JzCbocjgGgX44Bf/view?usp=sharing) so the z columns with the highest value are shown by colour.

Effectively a 2D contour plot, of this, seperated by colour:

[image]

Comment: Hi, you're more likely to get help if you provide us with a minimal, reproducible example - a minimal dataset *in code form* rather than a link to a google sheet. If you're not sure how to do this, please see here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/13968222)

Comment: Hi Cameron. This is essentially the same question you asked before. The answer is  'yes, but it looks terrible`. I already showed you the viable options. Because you are assuming radial symmetry, all you have is a bunch of concentric circles. Having three different colored sets of concentric circles which overlap in many places just makes for an incredibly confusing plot. I tried with overlapped colors too, and it is just a mess. Nothing you could do in 3D would be as clear as the plot you have in your question. It's not that it can't be done - more that it shouldn't be done

Comment: I'm happy to show you other versions of what I tried before, but the last plot in my previous answer is a plot of the highest color value at each point in the field, which seems to be what you are asking for here. All you get is a single solid circle in a field of another color.